# É possível treinar um modelo quando possuo apenas uma das classes mapeada?

Tags: aprendizagem-de-máquina

Eu tenho um grande conjunto de dados (~ 1.700.000) que eu gostaria de classificar. Eu também tenho uma amostra não tão pequena (~ 8.000) classificada como uma dessas classes (digamos, condição A), mas eu não tenho nenhuma (zero) das outras classes (digamos, condições B a Z). Além disso, todas variáveis são categóricas.

Apesar de haverem inúmeras categorias, tenho interesse apenas em um delas (aquela que possuo alguma amostra, de condição A).

Sou capaz de treinar o modelo com apenas as observações de tipo A? Se não, como devo superar esse problema?

É razoável alterar a forma do problema para uma classificação de tipo binário (tipo A seriam VERDADEIRO e os demais tipos FALSO)? Neste caso, posso tomar aleatoriamente algumas das observações não classificadas e supor que a condição é FALSO? Sei que a maior parte das observações não classificadas seriam de tipo B a Z (no caso binário FALSO).

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Não me parece razoável alterar o problema para um classificador do tipo binário porque você não tem dados de treinamento para duas "classes" (A e não-A). Com dados de apenas uma classe não tem como criar um modelo para decidir a classe porque ele não tem como aprender as distinções.

Comment: Talvez uma abordagem que possa ser útil pra você é usar algum algoritmo de clusterização, como o [K-Médias](http://web.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/ana.freitas/bioinformatics.ath.cx/bioinformatics.ath.cx/index651a.html?id=147), nos grande conjunto de dados. Você não sabe quais são as classes, mas parece saber quantas são (esse seria o valor de K no K-Médias). Assim, talvez consiga ter uma separação que pode lhe ser útil ao menos pra diminuir a quantidade de dados e te permitir uma análise posterior (e aí sim, a construção de um classificador binário).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode transformar o problema em binário se sua suposição de que dentre os não classificados a maioria é falso, como você diz na sua pergunta. (O certo, seria não ter nenhum positivo dentro os não classificados, mas se for bem pequeno, provavelmente não irá atrapalhar)

> Sei que a maior parte das observações não classificadas seriam de tipo
>   B a Z (no caso binário FALSO).

Inclusive, muitos classificadores usam isso quando usam a estratégia [*one-vs-rest*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-rest)

Conforme a discussão dos comentários, destaco:

- se existirem observações da condição A dentro do seu banco de 1,7M e a sua amostra de 8.000 não for uma sub-amostra do conjunto de 1,7M, provavelmente essa não será a melhor abordagem.
- se a quantidade de observações de condição A do conjunto de 1,7M for realmente pequena, esse método apesar de ser viesado, terá melhor acerto do que selecionando aleatoriamente uma classe.

Comment: Mas como ele vai treinar o classificador binário se ele só tem amostras de uma das classes? (pelo que eu entendi ele não tem nenhuma amostra das classes B a Z)

Comment: @LuizVieira pelo que eu entendi, ele possui um banco de 1.700.000 mas só possui 8000 casos classificados, todos da classe A. Além disso, esses 8000 casos classificados correspondem a (praticamente) todos os casos de classe A dentre os 1.700.000.

Comment: Sim, mas nesse banco de 1.700.000 ele não sabe as classes (e quer justamente usar um classificador para separá-los). Se ele usar os 1.700.000 como "o resto", me parecem grandes as chances do classificador dele ficar errado. Não?

Comment: Além disso, não me parece que ele disse que os 8000 casos da classe A são os únicos (isto é, que nos 1.700.000 não existam amostras de A). De fato, ele diz: "*Sei que a maior parte das observações não classificadas seriam de tipo B a Z (no caso binário FALSO)*." Ou seja, ele sabe que *a maior parte* não são do tipo A, mas podem haver amostras de A nos 1.700.000. :/

Comment: Eu entendi a pergunta de um jeito totalmente diferente, mas acho que você tem razão. Você acha que o melhor é deletar a resposta?

Comment: De qualquer forma, um classificador construido desta forma é melhor do que o aleatório ou no mínimo igual.

Comment: Não, deixa a resposta. Ela ainda assim é útil, pois vc tem razão que mesmo assim talvez seja melhor do que escolher aleatoriamente. Mas eu ainda acho que o AP precisa fazer uma análise melhor dos dados (eu sugeri usar clusterização). Se ele conseguir separar exemplos negativos pra usar no treinamento, o classificador dele fica bem melhor. :)

Comment: Talvez só edite pra adicionar a sua observação final (de que um classificador construído assim talvez não fique bom, mas vai ser melhor do que escolher aleatoriamente). Aliás, se nos 1.700.000 realmente tem poucas amostras da classe A, o classificador vai errar mais em falso negativo do que em falso positivo. Talvez isso já seja bem útil para o AP.